# Casting pointer to float

Tags: c#, pointers, casting

I have searched but I can't find a good answer for my problem I hope someone can help me.
I have some functions that write c# variable into a buffer at an offset location. I have a function like the one below. This WriteFloat function works and it gets all the bytes correctly.

```
    public unsafe void WriteFloat(float v, byte[] m_Buffer,int m_Offset )
    {
        ValidateBufferSize(sizeof(float));

        fixed ( byte* buf = m_Buffer )
            *(float*)(buf + m_Offset) = v;

        m_Offset += sizeof(float);
    }
```

I also have for each type a read function that can read back the value from the buffer. The  offset is where we left off after the last read.

```
    public unsafe float ReadFloat( byte[] m_Buffer,int m_Offset)
    {
        fixed (byte* buf = m_Buffer)
        {
            float v = *((float*)(buf + m_Offset));
            m_Offset += sizeof(float);
            return v;
        }

    }
```

Here is the problem. float is the only variable that I currently don't support because my ReadFloat Function always return the wrong value.

Ex : this is the buffer  after we wrote to the buffer (Note: don't mind the first 4 bytes) the last 4 byte is the short  5.5f = 00 00 b0 40

08 00 01 01 00 00 b0 40

When I use the readFloat function on that buffer it always return 0;

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the right way

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float  input = 123.45F;
            byte[] array = new byte[4];
            WriteFloat(input, ref array, 0);
            float output = ReadFloat(array, 0);
        }
        static public void WriteFloat(float v, ref byte[] m_Buffer, int m_Offset)
        {
            BitConverter.GetBytes(v).CopyTo(m_Buffer, m_Offset);
        }
        static public float ReadFloat(byte[] m_Buffer, int m_Offset)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToSingle(m_Buffer, m_Offset);

        }
    }
}
​
```